# Powershell: How can I extract time from the message field of eventlog?

Tags: powershell, event-log, get-eventlog

I'm trying to get unexpected shutdown times of Windows Sever 2008 machines via `Get-EventLog` in Powershell. I can get close by searching for events with an `EventID` of 6008 and selecting only `message`, but I need to parse within the field to grab the time it occurred (not the time the event fired).

I've tried to use `replacementstrings[x]` but I can't find how to specify the field to use (`messages`) and can't get a result.

`get-eventlog -LogName System -ComputerName svr-name | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 6008 -AND $_.timegenerated -gt (get-date).adddays(-30)}| select message`

Produces this:

```
Message
-------
The previous system shutdown at 3:35:32 AM on ‎7/‎29/‎2014 was unexpected.
The previous system shutdown at 3:40:06 PM on ‎7/‎10/‎2014 was unexpected.`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retrieving all events from a remote host and filtering them on the local machine ususally doesn't perform too well, because that way you transmit tons of unrelated events over the network, just to throw them away. [`Get-EventLog`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849834.aspx) has options for filtering messages by Event ID or before/after a given timestamp on the source, so better use those for pre-selecting the messages you're actually interested in. The timestamp of the crash can be extracted from the `Message` field with a regular expression and parsed into a `DateTime` value via [`ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
$log     = 'System'
$server  = 'svr-name'
$id      = [uint64]"0x80000000" + 6008
$date    = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

$fmt     = 'h:mm:ss tt on M\/d\/yyyy'
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

Get-EventLog -LogName $log -ComputerName $server -InstanceId $id -After $date | ? {
  $_.Message -match 'at (\d+:\d+:\d+ [ap]m on \d+/\d+/\d+) was unexpected'
} | select MachineName, TimeGenerated,
           @{n='Crashtime';e={[DateTime]::ParseExact($matches[1], $fmt, $culture)}}
```

The pipeline produces a list of objects with the properties `MachineName`, `TimeGenerated` and `Crashtime` (the last one being a [calculated property](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx)). If you collect the output of the pipeline in a variable (e.g. `$evt`) you can access the `Crashtime` property of the third object like this:

```
$evt = .\script.ps1
$evt[2].Crashtime
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `InstanceID` filter. I found that the `EventID` doesn't necessarily correspond to `InstanceID`; in this case `EventID` `6008` = `2137489656 `. I'm still new to Powershell, and I'm having trouble following your array population on line 12 (@...). How can I call elements of this array (e.g.`$Crashtime[2]`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kiwisan: ITYM 2147489656 (which is 6008 + 0x80000000). I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex, you can pull it out as such.

```
$Messages = (get-eventlog -LogName System -ComputerName svr-name | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 6008 -AND $_.timegenerated -gt (get-date).adddays(-30) }| select message)
$Messages | ForEach-Object { 
    $Matched = $_.Message -match "([0-9]{1,2}:.*[0-9]{4})"
    if ($Matched) {
        Write-Output "System rebooted at $($Matches[1])" 
    }
}
```

There might be a better way, but I do not know what :)

**Example Output from my System**

```
System rebooted at 4:34:30 PM on ‎4/‎20/‎2014
System rebooted at 1:48:38 PM on ‎1/‎21/‎2014
System rebooted at 1:37:12 PM on ‎1/‎21/‎2014
System rebooted at 1:22:01 PM on ‎1/‎21/‎2014
System rebooted at 4:41:21 PM on ‎11/‎22/‎2013
```

Answer (score 1):

More easy

```
get-eventlog system  | where-object {$_.EventID -eq  "6008"} | fl
```